# If the model layers are frozen, what is the difference between .fit() and .predict() for a separate dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, transfer-learning

I am trying to do transfer learning involving two Datasets: D1 and D2.

D1 has around 22,000 samples, 15 labels, and D2 with around 8,000 samples and 9 labels. Both the datasets have the same labelling methods, i.e. Label 1 in D1 would mean the same thing as Label 1 in D2, and so on; it's just that D2 doesn't have data for all the 15 labels D1 has. I train the model on the D1 dataset with an 80-20 train-test split, and it gives me an accuracy of around 85% (with validation accuracy =83%). I then use this model to make predictions on the D2 dataset using the `.predict()` method and calculate the accuracy as follows :

```
from sklearn import metrics 

score = metrics.accuracy_score(labels, prediction_list)

print(score)
```

This returns an accuracy of around 12%, which is really bad. But when I load the initial model and freeze all the layers whilst adding an additional layer just for prediction and then use the `.fit()` method on the D2 dataset with the same 80-20 split, the accuracy that I get is around 87% (with validation accuracy =84%).

```
model_experiment.layers
# Output : 

[<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x7fce74310e90>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x7fce76ef9250>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x7fce6e7d32d0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization_v2.BatchNormalization at 0x7fce7482e750>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x7fce75e1f410>]

dependencies = {
     'f1_m': f1_m,
     'precision_m': precision_m,
     'recall_m': recall_m
}
model_experiment = models.load_model('model_experiment.h5', custom_objects=dependencies)
for i in range(3):
  model_experiment.layers[i].trainable = False


k1 = model_experiment.layers[2].output
k1 = BatchNormalization()(k1)
k1 = Dense(9,activation="softmax")(k1)

transfer_learning_model = models.Model(inputs=model_experiment.input,outputs=k1)

transfer_learning_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['acc',f1_m,precision_m, recall_m])

transfer_learning_model.fit(X_train, y_train , epochs=30, batch_size = 64,validation_data=(X_test, y_test),callbacks=[lr_reduce], verbose=1)
```

Why did the accuracy change so much even when the layers of the model were frozen? Shouldn't the `.fit()` method and `.predict()` method return similar values when all the layers are frozen, and the classification labels are the same for D1 and D2?

Comment: `.fit()` is only for train model. `.predict()` is for predict new values - and to get `score` to see if model works correctly.

Comment: I know that but I was wondering why would the accuracy differ so much for `.fit()` and `.predict()` on a different dataset if the model layers are frozen.